# unable to lock a non-root RHEL account using pam_tally2.so PAM module

Tags: linux, rhel-5, pam

I have RHEL 5.5 and making the below change in `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` file:

```
    auth        required      pam_env.so 
    auth        required      pam_tally2.so deny=3 onerr=fail
    auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
    auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 500 quiet
    auth        required      pam_deny.so


    account     required      pam_tally2.so
    account     required      pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
    account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 500 quiet
    account     required      pam_permit.so
```

But this doesn't work as expected. After some failed logins, I do see the `account locked` message, but it stills asks for password after that, and even if I put correct password it shows the below:

```
[student@server3 ~]$ su - testuser
Your account is locked. Maximum amount of failed attempts was reached.
Password: 
su: incorrect password
```

But as a `root` user I can still login to the user:

```
[root@server3 ~]# su - testuser
[testuser@server3 ~]$
```

which tells that the user is actually not locked. Isn't it correct? What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing wrong, this is the expected behaviour. As root, you bypass authentication.

Not everyone has root access, hopefully...